# How to persist entities from an embedded form submission?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a `Person` entity and an `Address` entity, set up with a bi-directional one-to-one relationship, with the FK on `Address`:

```
...

class Person
{
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Address", mappedBy="person")
     */
    protected $address;
    ...
}

...

class Address
{
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="address")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="personID", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $person;
}
```

The `Address` Entity does NOT have a dedicated primary key, it instead derives its identity through the foreign key relationship with `Person`, as [explained here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html)

The form I have for creating a new Person also embeds the form for Address. When the form is submitted, this controller action is executed:

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $person = new Person();

    $form = $this->createCreateForm($person);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($person);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('people'));
    }

    return array(
        'person' => $person,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

I've inspected the data, and `$person` has its `$address` property filled out with the proper form details as expected. However, once the `$person` object is persisted, I get the error:

> A new entity was found through the relationship
>   'Acme\AcmeBundle\Entity\Person#address' that was not configured to
>   cascade persist operations for entity...

I've tried a couple of things and none seem to work:

1. Setting `cascade={"persist"}` on the OneToOne relationship definition on the Person object. Doing so results in error:

> Entity of type Acme\AcmeBundle\Entity\Address is missing an assigned
>   ID for field 'person'...
>
> On the `Person#setAddress` method, I've taken the `$address` parameter and manually called `$address->setPerson($this)` on it. Doesn't work either.
>
> It seems like my problem is that Doctrine is trying to save the `Address` object before saving the `Person` object, and it can't because it needs to know the ID of the associated `Person` first.

For instance, If I alter the the persist code to something like this, it works:

```
...
// Pull out the address data and remove it from the Person object
$address = $person->getAddress();
$person->setAddress(null);

// Save the person object and flush so we get an ID
$em->persist($person);
$em->flush();

// Now set the person object on the address and save the address
$address->setPerson($person);
$em->persist($address);
$em->flush();
...
```

How can I do this properly? I want to retain the ability to embed forms with this type of one-to-one relationship, but things are starting to get complicated. How do I get Doctrine to flush the `$person` object before flushing the `$address` object, without manually doing it myself like above?

Answer (score 4):

Keep the cascade=persist.

Then modify Person::setAddress

```
class Person
{
    public function setAddress($address)
    {
        $this->address = $address;
        $address->setPerson($this); //*** This is what you are missing ***
```

This is a very common question but it's hard to search for.

Comment: This results in the error: `Entity of type Acme\AcmeBundle\Entity\Address has identity through a foreign entity Acme\AcmeBundle\Entity\Person, however this entity has no identity itself. You have to call EntityManager#persist() on the related entity and make sure that an identifier was generated before trying to persist 'Acme\AcmeBundle\Entity\DetailsCS'. In case of Post Insert ID Generation (such as MySQL Auto-Increment or PostgreSQL SERIAL) this means you have to call EntityManager#flush() between both persist operations`. Based on this helpful error, I may indeed need to use my "workaround"

Comment: I would give the address entity it's own simple auto-increment id and make person a regular relation instead of the primary id. Yes it's an extra database column but I think you will find it saves a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Your mapping is incorrect. You are using `@ORM\Id` incorrectly on $person.

If you haven't yet, add a real $id to Address and add again `cascade={"persist"}.

```
class Person
{
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Address", mappedBy="person", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $address;
    ...
}

...

class Address
{
    ...
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="address")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="personID", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $person;
}
```

If Person were the owning side, Address should also be automatically persisted by Doctrine, don't know your model but maybe you should consider changing it.

Comment: I actually don't want to add a dedicated primary key on `Address`. See [this page](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html) which explains I'm using the foreign key as a primary key for `Address`

Comment: I updated my question to include that detail, which I should have done  originally.